# Redstone door lock (memory cell)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to make a pvp map which has 2 spawnpoints on the map. The spawnpoints are closed off with an iron door. The teams can both get ready by flipping a lever. Now i want to make it so when both teams are ready the doors open. This could be achieved by a memory cell. I know because i have made these before but i cant remember how to build this and i also knew it wouldn't work if i added more doors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couldn't you use a AND gate? A memory cell seems overkill for this sort of thing.

An AND gate:
[image]

1 Lever in "Ready" Position:
[image]

2 Levers in "Ready" Position (doors open)
[image]

You could also consider using command blocks to teleport the team/players into the arena when a button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks this would work, pretty simple. The reason i dont want to use command blocks is that some players will always load faster then the other so they might have an advantage.

Comment: This will also work with more than two doors; just ensure that the signal from one lever can span the whole row, and that the doors are receiving the "on" signal. Use repeaters as necessary; to keep it fair, you should make each door delayed by the same amount. You could even incorporate some sort of timer (starting in 3... 2... 1... GO!) with command blocks and the `/say <message>` command.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but it seems you just need an AND gate, with the two levers as inputs and the doors connected to the output, that way, when lever A AND B are turned on the doors will open.

Comment: And do you have any examples on how to make an AND gate?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma It's not a hard thing to look up: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Redstone_Circuits/Logic#AND_Gate_.28.E2.88.A7.29

Answer (score 0):

A simple AND gate with a latch to make sure that the doors won't close if the teams decide to mess around with the levers would work nicely.

I'd personally use an SR latch, assuming that you want to reset the map for another round, where the output of the AND gate is connected to the Set input, and the reset button wired to the Reset input.